# maximum possible number of turns for a coin flipping game

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, puzzle

8 coins are in a row and numbered from left to right.

For each turn, we count number of heads. If see k heads among these 8 coins, we flip the k-th coin (H to T, vice versa).

We stop until we see 8 tails and no heads.

What's the maximal number of turns until we stop?

My thoughts: say it's all tails first and the 8th one is head, then we flip from 1 to 7, change them all to heads. Then we change them back to tails. But how do I prove this is maximum?

My thoughts 2: TTTTHHHH will take 36 flips apparently

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @CalvinLin added

Comment: Try induction on the number of coins $n$.  When do you flip the $n$th coin?

Comment: Your guess is not maximum. E.g. $THTHTHTH$ takes 17 flips.

Comment: @CalvinLin  TTTTHHHH will take 36 flips apparently

Comment: Nice one! It certainly takes a lot of flips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually interesting.

Let's say there are $n$ coins, and we want to find the maximum flips.

It turns out that,

> for $n$ even, the maximum is attained at `TT...THH..H`, with $n/2$ `T` and $n/2$ `H`;
>
> for $n$ odd, the maximum is attained at `T...THH...H`, with $(n - 1)/2$ `T` and $(n + 1)/2$ `H`.

In both cases, the maximun number of flips is $n(n+1)/2$, and the configuration attaining the max is unique.

---

I'll leave the proof to others, because it's time for bed...

---

Seems nobody else wants to give a proof ...

OK here we go.

Let $M(n)$ be the maximum number of flips among all configurations of $n$ coins. For such a configuration, there are two possibilities:

1. The $n$-th coin is `T`. Then the $n$-th coin will always remain `T`, until the end of the game. Hence it is essentially a game with $n - 1$ coins and the maximum number of flips is no more than $M(n - 1)$.
2. The $n$-th coin is `H`. Then the $n$-th coin will still remain `H`, until the configuration `HH...H` is reached. After that, it's easy to see that $n$ more flips leads to the final configuration `TT...T`.

   Therefore it suffices to consider the number of flips until the configuration `HH...H`.

   Now we reindex the coins: previously they were indexed $1, 2, \dotsc, n$, and now we index them as $n - 1, \dotsc, 1, 0$. Under this new index system, the rule of flipping becomes: if there are $k$ **tails** among the first $n - 1$ coins, then we flip the coin with new index $k$. The procedure continues until all the first $n - 1$ coins are `H`, i.e. we reach the configuration `HH...H`.

   This is then exactly the same game with $n - 1$ coins, and with heads and tails exchanged. Thus the maximum number of flips until the configuration `HH...H` is $M(n - 1)$, and hence the total maximum number of flips (until the configuration `TT...T`) is $M(n - 1) + n$.

Combining 1. and 2., we get $M(n) = M(n - 1) + n$, and the maximum is attained only when the last coin is `H`, and the first $n - 1$ coins attain the maximum for the game with $n - 1$ coins, with `H` and `T` switched and order inversed.

By induction on $n$, this proves exactly our claims.